# JBoss EAP 7 to act like Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.x

Tags: activemq-artemis

is it possible to configure JBoss EAP 7 to act like Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.x?

For example to gain functionality to connect to JBoss EAP 7 queues via port 61616 without http-remoting.

The queues should not have to be connected to any MDB, i.e. to act as a broker for subset of all queues.

Is is possible to set it up in this way without any additional resource adapters?

Regards

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the instance of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP 7 like you would use a stand-alone instance of ActiveMQ Artemis, but it won't be quite as flexible or as simple to configure because EAP uses ActiveMQ Artemis essentially as a JMS implementation only.

If you use the JNDI `IntialContextFactory` from the ActiveMQ Artemis core JMS client (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`) then you don't need to use the JNDI lookup based on `http-remoting` that's normally used with JBoss EAP.